# How to efficiently instantiate instance variables across multiple controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

consider the following instance variables

```
@categories = Category.all
@posts = Post.order("created_at DESC")
```

i want to use them across multiple controllers as part of the footer, what is the most efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see TWO ways to do so:

**FIRST:**

I would do it using inheritance.

```
class GenericController < ApplicationController
  // Declare your class variables here
end
```

and then

```
class MyController01 < GenericController

end

class MyController01 < GenericController

end

. 
.
.
```

Then the class variables would be available in the descendant classes.

**SECOND:**

Another possibility, easier to implement, is putting these variable directly in **app/controller/application_controller.rb**. Remember all controllers are descendant of this one.

Then you may just use these variables directly in your layout(s) and everything will be fine.

Comment: I added a new possibility of solution to your answer. If you find one of the solutions useful, please accept it in order to help those who helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer composition to inheritance. So, I might create

```
# app/controllers/shared_methods/load_footer_variables.rb
module SharedMethods
  module LoadFooterVariables

    def load_footer_variables
      @categories = Category.all
      @posts = Post.order("created_at DESC")
    end

  end
end
```

Now, in every controller where you want to load your footer variables, do

```
#app/controllers/foo_controller.rb
class FooController < ApplicationController

  include SharedMethods::LoadFooterVariables
  before_action :load_footer_variables, :only => [:method_a, :method_b]

  def method_a
    ...
  end

  def method_b
    ...
  end

  def method_c
    ...
  end

end
```

The `include SharedMethods::LoadFooterVariables` call makes the methods in the module available within the controller. The `before_action` call instructs the controller to call the `load_footer_variables` method prior to `method_a` and `method_b` (but not `method_c`).

If you always want the `load_footer_variables` called for every action in the controller, then omit the `:only` argument. You can also use `:except` if it's more convenient to exclude action rather than include them.

Comment: That's a nice solution!